Issues Integrating React Frontend with CodeIgniter 4 Backend on Shared Hosting - 404 and 500 Errors
Hello Stack Overflow Community, I am working on a project where I am trying to integrate a React frontend with a CodeIgniter 4 backend where both the frontend and backend are hosted on a shared hosting environment..
In theory this should be simple.. However, I am running into several issues related to API routing and server configuration. Despite trying many different .htaccess configurations and troubleshooting steps I am still getting either 404 errors or intercepted by React when making API calls from the React frontend.
My project directory looks like this:
```
# /public_html/
# │
# ├── /instructor_frontend/     
# │   └── /build/                
# │
# ├── /instructor_web_new/      
# │   └── /public/               
# │       └── .htaccess         
# │
# |___ .htaccess
```

Goal:

Serve the React app from /instructor_frontend/build/index.html.

Forward all /api requests to CodeIgniter (/instructor_web_new/public/index.php).

Ensure React serves the frontend, but CodeIgniter handles API requests.


The Problem:

React Intercepting API Requests: When I make requests like instructor.greenhorndriving.com/api/test, I receive a 200 OK status, but instead of returning the expected response from CodeIgniter, I get the HTML content of the React app.

404 Errors: I receive 404 errors when I make requests to /api endpoints after running npm run build for the React app. This is because the .htaccess file in /instructor_frontend/build/ resets to default settings after the build, causing the API requests to no longer route correctly.


When I use npm run build my .htaccess in instructor_frontend resets to:
```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^instructor\.greenhorndriving\.com$ [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.instructor\.greenhorndriving\.com$
   RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/instructor\.greenhorndriving\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

So when I update the .htaccess in the /build directory to the following configuration:
```

.  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api
   RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /instructor_web_new/public/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

    # Ensure HTTPS redirection
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^instructor\.greenhorndriving\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.instructor\.greenhorndriving\.com$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "https://instructor.greenhorndriving.com/" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>`
```

and make requests to /api or even visit instructor.greenhorndriving.com/api/test I receive a 200 OK status, but instead of returning the expected API response from the backend, the API endpoints return the HTML content of the React app.
Screenshot of /api/test displaying React HTML after changing .htaccess
I even made the following changes to the root .htaccess in public_html but to avail:
```
# Serve static resources like manifest.json directly from the file system
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^instructor\.greenhorndriving\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]

# Route API requests to the CodeIgniter backend
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^instructor\.greenhorndriving\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /instructor_web_new/public/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

# Route requests to the React app (frontend) for any remaining paths
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^instructor\.greenhorndriving\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /instructor_frontend/build/index.html [L]
```

My CodeIgniter Routes.php located in (app/Config/Routes.php)
```
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
$routes->get('api/test', function() {
    return "Work Pls....";
});

$routes->group('api', function($routes) {
    $routes->post('login', 'AuthController::login');
    $routes->post('logout', 'AuthController::logout');
});

I created an AuthController.php located in (app/Controllers/AuthController.php):
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\UserModel;
use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;

class AuthController extends ResourceController
{
    public function login()
    {
        $model = new UserModel();
        $email = $this->request->getPost('email');
        $password = $this->request->getPost('password');
        $encodedPassword = base64_encode($password);
        $device_type = $this->request->getPost('device_name');
        $device_token = $this->request->getPost('device_token');

        $user = $model->where('email', $email)
                      ->where('role', 'instructor')
                      ->where('auth_level', 3)
                      ->first();

        if ($user) {
            if ($user['user_status'] == 1) {
                if ($encodedPassword === $user['password']) {
                    $model->update($user['id'], [
                        'device_name' => $device_type,
                        'device_token' => $device_token
                    ]);

                    session()->set([
                        'user_id' => $user['id'],
                        'email' => $user['email'],
                        'role' => $user['role']
                    ]);

                    return $this->respond([
                        'status' => 1,
                        'message' => 'Logged in successfully.',
                        'data' => [
                            'email' => $user['email'],
                            'role' => $user['role']
                        ]
                    ], 200);
                } else {
                    return $this->respond(['status' => 0, 'message' => 'Invalid credentials.'], 401);
                }
            } else {
                return $this->respond(['status' => 0, 'message' => 'Your account has been Inactive, Please contact the administrator.'], 403);
            }
        } else {
            return $this->respond(['status' => 0, 'message' => 'This email is not registered.'], 401);
        }
    }

    public function logout()
        {
        session()->destroy();
        return $this->respond(['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Logged out successfully.'], 200);
        }
    }

Overall I want to know why are my /api requests still being intercepted by the React app instead of being routed to CodeIgniter even after modifying the .htaccess?
Thank you so much for your time and expertise!
My server has mod_rewrite enabled and that the AllowOverride All directive is set in the Apache virtual host configuration.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / - do you really have all of this on one line? If so, I'd rather expect that to throw an error.

You would need to place your modifications after the HTTPS rewrite, if you want that one still to work - otherwise, the L flag in the previous rules will never let it get there, if those apply. Plus, RewriteRule ^/?$ is rather weird - that'd mean this redirect happens only for the root URL.

As already asked on Staging Ground:  what does your error log tell you about the 500 errors? Are the 404 errors really related to React or Apache, or is the application itself unable to serve anything at the routes throwing the error?

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api is quite superfluous, when the following rule matches on ^api/(.*)$. And since the next condition is the exact opposite, you should be able to simply write these two RewriteRules one after another, without any RewriteCond before either of them.

On shared hosting you will likely not be able to enable rewrite logging yourself, but maybe you can ask support to do it for you - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging That would help to retrace what is actually going on.
